# Why is the jquery_update module not supporting the latest jQuery version?

Tags: 7, javascript

The recommended jquery_update module only supports 1.10. Why recent jQuery security version 3.4.1 not updated?
https://jquery.com/download/

So is it recommended to make my Drupal site to update with latest jQuery version for security reasons?

When I try to make the module to support latest jquery version, I am facing issues with other jQuery UI files. What are the additional UI files need to be addressed to work with latest jQuery version?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the latest dev version of jQuery update, `7.x-3.x-dev` to get the latest version of jQuery, or at least jQuery 3.1.  [See this drupal issue for more insight](https://www.drupal.org/node/2649142).

[You can see in the `7.x-3.x` dev branch, it has jQuery 3.1](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jquery_update/blob/7.x-3.x/replace/jquery/3.1/jquery.js).

Note, there is also a [patch for jQuery 3.2, 3.3, and 3.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update/issues/3053169) against the `7.x-2.7` branch.